# Binary classification of sensor data using minimal code space

Tags: c, classification, sensors, low-memory

[image: Sensor Data]

I am trying to classify the events above as 1 or 0. 1 would be the lower values and 0 would be the higher values. Usually the data is does not look as clean as this. Currently the approach I am taking is to have two different thresholds so that in order to go from 0 to 1 it has to go past the 1 to 0 threshold and it has to be above for 20 sensor values. This threshold is set to the highest value I receive minus ten percent of that value. I dont think a machine learning approach will work because I have too few features to work with and also  the implementation has to take up minimal code space. I am hoping someone may be able to point me in the direction of a known algorithm that would apply well to this sort of problem, googling it and checking my other sources isnt producing great results. The current implementation is very effective and the hardware inst going to change.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan.  What's the question?

Comment: It dosnt work very well. I was hoping someone may have an algorithm or an approach that would work better. I have looked for one online and everything is pointing to logistic regression which wont work.

Comment: Do you have a constant time interval for each period that you wish to assign 0 or 1 to?

Comment: "Machine-learning?" Why not compare with a running average? AKA **filter**.

Comment: @EricJ I am not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: @WeatherVane So you are saying if the average begins to increase, then say that it is equal to 0 and if it decreases it is 1? Rather than using a set thresholds look at the rate of change?

Comment: You might also like to look up *hysteresis* and develop an algorithm to prevent the `0/1` flipping too readily in response to local disturbances.

Answer (score 2):

> Currently the approach I am taking is to have two different thresholds so that in order to go from 0 to 1 it has to go past the 1 to 0 threshold and it has to be above for 20 sensor values

Calculate the area on your graph of those 20 sensor values.  If the area is greater than a threshold (perhaps half the peak value) assign it as 1, else assign it as 0.

Since your measurements are one unit wide (pixels, or sensor readings) the area ends up being the sum of the 20 sensor values.

Comment: Hmmm I like this idea rather than making sure all 20 values are above the threshold I could try taking the running average of the last 20 and see if that is above the threshold.

Comment: The running average of the last 20 is essentially the same as the area of the last 20.